# SQL Query to calculate the AVG of DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I'm trying to write a query that gives me a gives me the `AVG` of a `Datediff`

I have a similar query that I am trying to replicate with my new and here it is:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, d.OPENED) AS MonthValue, 
SUM(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS = 2 THEN 
1 ELSE 0 END) AS SmallCommercialIndust, 
SUM(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS <> 2 THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END) AS Residential
FROM hb_Disputes d
WHERE YEAR(d.OPENED) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, d.OPENED) 
ORDER BY MIN(d.OPENED);
```

Here is my output:

```
Month Value  Small Commercial Indust     Residential
----------------------------------------------------
January             0                         0
February            0                         0
March               1                         0
April               0                         2
May                 0                         1
June                0                         1
July                1                         0
August              1                         0
September           0                         1
October             1                         0
November            1                         0
December            0                         1
```

Below is the `Query` I am attempting to create, which takes the same information but adds an additional component where it takes `d.OPENS` and subtract it to `d.DATERLVD` and provide me with the `AVG` for the month:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, d.OPENED) AS MonthValue, 
SUM(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS = 2 THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END AND AVG(DATEDIFF(day, d.OPENED, d.DATERLVD)) AS 
SmallCommercialIndust, 
SUM(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS <> 2  THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END AND AVG(DATEDIFF(day, d.OPENED, d.DATERLVD)) AS 
Residential
FROM hb_Disputes d
WHERE YEAR(d.OPENED) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, d.OPENED)
ORDER BY MIN(d.OPENED);
```

Comment: Just replace the `AND` with a `,`.

Comment: I'm still getting the following error `The SUM function requires 1 argument(s)` and when I attempt to `execute` I am getting a `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `AND` in the `SELECT` clause?  I think you want:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, d.OPENED) AS MonthValue, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SmallCommercialIndust,
       AVG(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS = 2 THEN DATEDIFF(day, d.OPENED, d.DATERLVD) END) AS SmallCommercialIndust_avg, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS <> 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Residential,
       AVG(CASE WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS <> 2 THEN DATEDIFF(day, d.OPENED, d.DATERLVD) END) AS Residential_avg
FROM hb_Disputes d
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to format your code properly.  You can see clearly that you put brackets at the wrong place.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, d.OPENED) AS MonthValue
    , SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS = 2 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END 
        AND 
            AVG(DATEDIFF(day, d.OPENED, d.DATERLVD)
    ) AS SmallCommercialIndust
    , SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN d.ASSGNTO = 'E099255' AND d.REV_CLS <> 2  THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END
        AND AVG(DATEDIFF(day, d.OPENED, d.DATERLVD)
    ) AS Residential
FROM hb_Disputes d
WHERE YEAR(d.OPENED) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, d.OPENED)
ORDER BY MIN(d.OPENED);
```